# Gmail filter to see emails I never replied to

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Is there a quick way to search or filter my Gmail inbox to see all the emails I never replied to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on "quick". here is quick tutorial:

- go to **https://script.google.com/home**
- on the top left there is **<kbd>New script</kbd>** button
- a new tab opens, wait to load and then press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>A</kbd>**
- next press **<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>** to remove everything unnecessary
- copy and then paste this code:

```
/*
 * This script goes through your Gmail Inbox and finds recent emails where you
 * were the last respondent. It applies a nice label to them, so you can
 * see them in Priority Inbox or do something else.
 *
 * To remove and ignore an email thread, just remove the unrespondedLabel and
 * apply the ignoreLabel.
 *
 * This is most effective when paired with a time-based script trigger.
 *
 * For installation instructions, read this blog post:
 * http://jonathan-kim.com/2013/Gmail-No-Response/
 */
```

// Edit these to your liking.
var unrespondedLabel = 'No Response',
    ignoreLabel = 'Ignore No Response',
    minTime = '5d',   // 5 days
    maxTime = '14d';  // 14 days

// Mapping of Gmail search time units to milliseconds.
var UNIT_MAPPING = {
    h: 36e5,    // Hours
    d: 864e5,   // Days
    w: 6048e5,  // Weeks
    m: 263e7,   // Months
    y: 3156e7   // Years
};

var ADD_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT = 100;
var REMOVE_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT = 100;

function main() {
  processUnresponded();
  cleanUp();
}

function processUnresponded() {
  // Define all the filters.
  var filters = [
    'is:sent',
    'from:me',
    '-in:chats',
    '(-subject:"unsubscribe" AND -"This message was automatically generated by Gmail.")',
    'older_than:' + minTime,
    'newer_than:' + maxTime
  ];

var threads = GmailApp.search(filters.join(' ')),
      threadMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads),
      unrespondedThreads = [],
      minTimeAgo = new Date();

minTimeAgo.setTime(subtract(minTimeAgo, minTime));

Logger.log('Processing ' + threads.length + ' threads.');

// Filter threads where I was the last respondent.
  threadMessages.forEach(function(messages, i) {
    var thread = threads[i],
        lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1],
        lastFrom = lastMessage.getFrom(),
        lastTo = lastMessage.getTo(),  // I don't want to hear about it when I am sender and receiver
        lastMessageIsOld = lastMessage.getDate().getTime() < minTimeAgo.getTime();

```
if (isMe(lastFrom) && !isMe(lastTo) && lastMessageIsOld && !threadHasLabel(thread, ignoreLabel)) {
  unrespondedThreads.push(thread);
}
```

})

// Mark unresponded in bulk.
  markUnresponded(unrespondedThreads);
  Logger.log('Updated ' + unrespondedThreads.length + ' messages.');
}

function subtract(date, timeStr) {
  // Takes a date object and subtracts a Gmail-style time string (e.g. '5d').
  // Returns a new date object.
  var re = /^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)$/,
      parts = re.exec(timeStr),
      val = parts && parts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjU3R.png),
      unit = parts && parts[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Tew.png),
      ms = UNIT_MAPPING[unit];

return date.getTime() - (val * ms);
}

function isMe(fromAddress) {
  var addresses = getEmailAddresses();
  for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    var address = addresses[i],
        r = RegExp(address, 'i');

```
if (r.test(fromAddress)) {
  return true;
}
```

}

return false;
}

function getEmailAddresses() {
  // Cache email addresses to cut down on API calls.
  if (!this.emails) {
    Logger.log('No cached email addresses. Fetching.');
    var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
        emails = GmailApp.getAliases();

```
emails.push(me);
this.emails = emails;
Logger.log('Found ' + this.emails.length + ' email addresses that belong to you.');
```

}
  return this.emails;
}

function threadHasLabel(thread, labelName) {
  var labels = thread.getLabels();

for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label = labels[i];

```
if (label.getName() == labelName) {
  return true;
}
```

}

return false;
}

function markUnresponded(threads) {
  var label = getLabel(unrespondedLabel);

// addToThreads has a limit of 100 threads. Use batching.
  if (threads.length > ADD_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(threads.length / ADD_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT); i++) {
        label.addToThreads(threads.slice(100 * i, 100 * (i + 1)));
    }
  } else {
      label.addToThreads(threads);
  }
}

function getLabel(labelName) {
  // Cache the labels.
  this.labels = this.labels || {};
  label = this.labels[labelName];

if (!label) {
    Logger.log('Could not find cached label "' + labelName + '". Fetching.', this.labels);

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);

if (label) {
  Logger.log('Label exists.');
} else {
  Logger.log('Label does not exist. Creating it.');
  label = GmailApp.createLabel(labelName);
}
this.labels[labelName] = label;
```

}
  return label;
}

function cleanUp() {
  var label = getLabel(unrespondedLabel),
      iLabel = getLabel(ignoreLabel),
      threads = label.getThreads(),
      expiredThreads = [],
      expiredDate = new Date();

expiredDate.setTime(subtract(expiredDate, maxTime));

if (!threads.length) {
    Logger.log('No threads with that label');
    return;
  } else {
    Logger.log('Processing ' + threads.length + ' threads.');
  }

threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    var lastMessageDate = thread.getLastMessageDate();

```
// Remove all labels from expired threads.
if (lastMessageDate.getTime() < expiredDate.getTime()) {
  Logger.log('Thread expired');
  expiredThreads.push(thread);
} else {
  Logger.log('Thread not expired');
}
```

});

```
// removeFromThreads has a limit of 100 threads. Use batching.
```

if (expiredThreads.length > REMOVE_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(expiredThreads.length / REMOVE_LABEL_TO_THREAD_LIMIT); i++) {
      label.removeFromThreads(expiredThreads.slice(100 * i, 100 * (i + 1)));
      iLabel.removeFromThreads(expiredThreads.slice(100 * i, 100 * (i + 1)));
    }
  } else {
      label.removeFromThreads(expiredThreads);
      iLabel.removeFromThreads(expiredThreads);
  }

Logger.log(expiredThreads.length + ' unresponded messages expired.');
}

- click on the clock icon [image]
- press **<kbd>OK</kbd>** button
- click on **`No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.`**
- change **Hour timer** to a different frequency if you want
- when done hit **<kbd>Save</kbd>** button
- then hit **<kbd>Review Permissions</kbd>** button
- select your account
- on the bottom left select **Advanced**
- scroll down and click on "Go to Untitled project (unsafe)"
- press that **<kbd>Allow</kbd>** button
- now open your Gmail (or reload with **<kbd>F5</kbd>** key) and when the trigger gets activated (based how you've set it up) you will see two new labels:

  - **Ignore No Response**
  - **No Response**

[image]