# Gmail search for emails from addresses I've never replied to

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-contacts

I'd like to find all emails in my inbox from addresses I've never sent an email to.

I've found this Q&A on searching for *emails* I've never replied to: [Gmail filter to see emails I never replied to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119582/gmail-filter-to-see-emails-i-never-replied-to)

But my goal is to find addresses with which I've never had a back and forth to sort and archive those.